# How to measure audio delay between two Asterisk channels?

Tags: audio, delay, asterisk

I have the following Setup:
A Centos machine with asterisk running that is connected to a Router via Ethernet. The Router answers the calls from my asterisk console and is itself again connected to my Centos machine via analogue RJ11 cable and a Digium PCI Card. (all for testing purposes of the router and running fine)
So I call and pick up the call at the same machine.

How can I now measure the delay between the audio of both channels?
I already tried to use the Monitor() function and evaluate delay signal based with cross correlation, but it seems like the Monitor function is not an accurate tool for recording at a precise time. (It doesn't start recording when I start the Playback() of my testfile)

Is there another possibility to get the delay between caller and callee?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Echo application on one end and send Beep on other end.

After that you can measure delay between beeps.

There are no any app which do such measure, but you can ask some developer do it for you.